# React Native android crash UIManager

Tags: react-native, expo

I made an android app with Expo and React-Native and since I upgraded to

```
// package.json
    "expo": "^20.0.0",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-20.0.0.tar.gz", // which is 0.47.0
    "exp": "44.0.0"

// app.json
    "sdkVersion": "20.0.0",
```

I get multiple exception of this kind:

```
abi20_0_0.com.facebook.react.uimanager.IllegalViewOperationException: 
  at abi20_0_0.com.facebook.react.uimanager.NativeViewHierarchyManager.resolveViewManager (NativeViewHierarchyManager.java:131)
  at abi20_0_0.com.facebook.react.uimanager.NativeViewHierarchyManager.manageChildren (NativeViewHierarchyManager.java:294)
  at abi20_0_0.com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$ManageChildrenOperation.execute (UIViewOperationQueue.java:177)
  at abi20_0_0.com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$1.run (UIViewOperationQueue.java:776)
  at abi20_0_0.com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue.flushPendingBatches (UIViewOperationQueue.java:855)
  at abi20_0_0.com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue.access$1600 (UIViewOperationQueue.java:46)
  at abi20_0_0.com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$DispatchUIFrameCallback.doFrameGuarded (UIViewOperationQueue.java:900)
  at abi20_0_0.com.facebook.react.uimanager.GuardedFrameCallback.doFrame (GuardedFrameCallback.java:31)
  at abi20_0_0.com.facebook.react.modules.core.ReactChoreographer$ReactChoreographerDispatcher.doFrame (ReactChoreographer.java:136)
  at abi20_0_0.com.facebook.react.modules.core.ChoreographerCompat$FrameCallback$1.doFrame (ChoreographerCompat.java:107)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:909)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:686)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:619)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:897)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7407)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1230)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

and

`abi20_0_0.com.facebook.react.uimanager.IllegalViewOperationException: Trying to add unknown view tag: 437`

and

`abi20_0_0.com.facebook.react.uimanager.IllegalViewOperationException: Trying to add unknown view tag: 8`

I'm using the UIManager to get a position in a scrollview and to use the LayoutAnimation (for the easeInEaseOut(), configureNext())

Anyone would know the problem/solution?

Thanks!